# What is Bison and why is it useful?

Tags: c++, c, bison

I have been programming for a few years now and have seen the name `Bison` in passing, but never bothered to ask why it is or why it might be needed. How can Bison effect how I program, can it make my C/C++ code faster?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison

Comment: Bison generates a parser from a formal grammar.  It has nothing whatsoever to do with making code faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bison is a parser generator. It takes it's input in something similar to Backus-Naur notation and outputs code to parse input according to that grammar. It lets you write a parser more easily than you would otherwise. Instead of having to do everything manually, you only have to specify the rules of your grammar and what you want to happen when it matches one of the rules.

Answer (score 2):

[GNU Bison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison) is the only Bison related to programming I know of. It won't make your code faster, and it's possible that you won't ever need it in your life. However, learning some compiler theory, or even writing a simple compiler yourself, is a terrific learning experience that does affect the way you program, the way you think about computer programming, and a lot of things like that. If you enjoy formal languages and automata, you'll enjoy compiler theory; if you dislike theory in general, it's probably not for you. If you're interested, there are lots of questions about starting books on Stackoverflow.

Oh and, once in a while a programmer does need some more complicated parsing work and suchlike, and it's a huge boon to know about parser generators, instead of writing everything by hand, following a naive approach.